# Is there a function $f(x, y, y')$ for which there are infinitely many solutions for every possible IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

To state it another way, does there exist a function $f(x, y, y')$ such that for each $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the IVP $f(x, y, y') = 0; y(x_0) = y_0$ has infinitely many solutions?

So far, I have checked functions that are not Lipschitz continuous, but for each of these functions only one IVP has infinitely many solutions. E. g. $y'=y^{1/3}$ has infinitely many solutions for $y(0)=0$. And I am wondering, is there any differential equation satisfying the conditions above?

Comment: How about something like $f(x,y,y') = \sin(y')$? Then for $k \in \mathbb Z$, $y = y_0+2k\pi(x-x_0)$ has $f(x,y,y') = \sin(y') = \sin(2k\pi) = 0$ and satisfies the initial value condition.

Comment: Your differential equation $y’ = y^{1/3}$ works.

Comment: In the book of P, Hartman: Ordinary differential equations, p.18 you can find the (rather effortful) construction of a function $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ such that for each choice of $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the IVP $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$, $y(x_0)=y_0$ has locally an infinite number of solutions (to the left and to the right).